# why there are so many build that are processing?was it taking longer because of that for test?

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7, archive

I still can't figure out why my new archive build 1.0.1 have too many processing data?I first uploaded my new build 1.0.1 to the iTunesconnect and because of internet connection,I cancelled it and upload again.I think its about 3 times i guess that I cancelled because of internet connection failure on my wifi.But,the 4th times,I completed uploaded and it show me 4 Processing File.Why there are so many processing build files?I only did successfully did uploaded to iTunes connect at 4:54 PM one archive of my new build.

Any help?

Was it these taking my build not to finish?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a question for Apple, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I want to know that is there anyone experiencing like me.

Comment: How long are you waiting for the builds to complete?

Comment: Finally I completed the last build,but there are still 3 which are processing.Actually they don't need to processing anymore because the latest build is completed.

Comment: I wonder why the remaining 3 processing build are stands for?